# How to do introspection in Swift?

Tags: swift, introspection

I notice properties that aren't defined anywhere in the Swift global definition, such as dynamicType and Type in Any.Type.  How do I find out the properties that one can access but aren't documented? Is there a way to do introspection in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift has read only reflection at this point. It's not that great yet, but here's an example of what's available:

```
struct Bookmark {
    let title: String, url: String
}

let bookmark = Bookmark(title: "Stack Overflow", url: "http://stackoverflow.com")

var mirror = reflect(bookmark)

for var propertyNumber = 0; propertyNumber < mirror.count; ++propertyNumber {
    let (propertyName, propertyMirror) = mirror[propertyNumber]
    println("\(propertyName) = \(propertyMirror.summary), \(propertyMirror.count) children")
}
```

Comment: Right now this gives an error in both the playground and the command line: data =Assertion failed: (ty->isLegalSILType() && "constructing SILType with type that should have been " "eliminated by SIL lowering"), function SILType, file /SourceCache/lldb_KLONDIKE/lldb_KLONDIKE-320.3.103/llvm/tools/swift/include/swift/SIL/SILType.h, line 73.
Abort trap: 6

Comment: It works for me when I make an Xcode project. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that.